# How do I change the user a C# service opens an excel application from?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, service, visual-studio-2015

I have an excel program that runs as soon as the excel file is opened. It's a huge program, so I cannot just rewrite it in C#. The program uses network paths that my user has permissions to.

In the ProjectInstaller in my service, I have set the Account as User, so I have to enter my user credentials each time I install the service. The service runs fine as my user.

The problem is however, when the service opens that excel program, it does not run it as my user, but as my local machine, so it doesn't have access to the network paths that it needs.

I run it like this:

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
WB1 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"\\Path\to\file");
//The excel file now executes a lot of code.
excelApp.Quit();
```

The excel app fails when it has to use the paths that my user has permissions to, but my local machine doesn't. I need to run the Excel application as my user, and not as the local machine. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Even though I have set visibile to true, it is not visible. It is set to true, because if I set it to false, it doesn't run any code in the application.

Comment: 1. Services do not have access to the console: no UI will ever be shown. 2. Use of any Office applications in a non-interactive environment (eg. from a service) is not supported (weird things may happen: you're on your own).